# Selenium Python Clicking an element the web page throws error when to capture the screenshot of the error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know how to capture a screenshot in Selenium Python but when to capture it?
Where to put it in the code.
My scenario: My selenium script clicked an element (a button) on a web page and an error dialog was shown. My test method couldn't continue because of the error dialog.
The script then moves onto the next test method which is fine.

I would like to capture the screenshot if an error is thrown when clicking an element.
On a click event an error dialog could occur, a 404 error page could appear etc.

Currently I have a custom method which finds an element and captures a screenshot if the element is not found.
My find_element method is:

```
# returns the element if found
def get_element(self, how, what):
    # params how: By locator type
    # params what: locator value
    try:
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print what
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        screenshot_name = how + what + get_datetime_now() # create screenshot name of the name of the element + locator + todays date time.  This way the screenshot name will be unique and be able to save
        self.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)
        raise
    return element

def save_screenshot(self, name):
    self.driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(Globals.screenshots_folder, name + '.png'))
    return self
```

How to capture a screenshot if an error page or error dialog appears on clicking an element?

Should I also capture a screenshot in the tear down method when the driver closes?
If there are any error during the tear down how and where to insert the capture a screenshot?

Thanks,
Riaz

My Solution:
I showed the answer, comment from Andrew Regan to my colleague and he suggested to put the try/catch block around every test method for the the test case.
I have done it in the following way.  My code snippet below of a test method:

```
def test_00001_add_all_records_report_CRM(self):
    try:
        print "*** Test add_all_records_report - CRM ***"
        self.login_page.userLogin_valid(Globals.login_username, Globals.login_password)
        tool_bar = ToolbarPage(self.driver)
        tool_bar.select_project_from_drop_down2("Analysis") 
        menu_bar = MenuBarPage(self.driver)
        reporting_page = menu_bar.select_menuBar_item("Reporting")
        project_navigator = ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
        reports_page = project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Reports")
        reports_page.click_add_button_for_reports()
        reports_manual_tab = reports_page.click_manual_tab()
        reports_manual_tab.enter_name_and_description_for_the_report_from_details_section("all_records", "This is an all records report")
        reports_manual_tab.click_type_dropdown_from_details_section("USN entities")
        reports_manual_tab.click_USN_category_link()
        reports_manual_tab.click_an_entity_from_usn_category_drop_down("All entities")
        reports_manual_tab.click_datasets_link()
        reports_manual_tab.uncheck_all_datasets_checkboxes() # untick all datasets checkboxes so we can start from a clean slate
        reports_manual_tab.click_a_dataset_checkbox_from_datasets_section("CRM")
        reports_manual_tab.click_variables_link()
        reports_manual_tab.click_all_variables_checkboxes_from_variables_section()
        reports_manual_tab.click_fields_link()
        reports_manual_tab.click_a_field_checkbox_from_fields_section("SOURCE_FIELDS", "Name")
        reports_manual_tab.click_a_field_checkbox_from_fields_section("SOURCE_FIELDS", "Address")
        reports_manual_tab.click_a_field_checkbox_from_fields_section("SOURCE_FIELDS", "DOB")
        reports_manual_tab.click_right_arrow_to_move_fields_to_selected_fields_listbox_from_fields_section()
        reports_page.click_save()
        project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Reports")             
        self.assertTrue(reports_page.is_report_details_saved("all_records", "This is an all records report", "USN entities"), "Problem with saved report. Please see log for details")
    except Exception:
        base_page = BasePage(self.driver)
        base_page.save_screenshot("test_00001_add_all_records_report_CRM")
        raise
```

When my test method failed, it did create the screenshot. Is it ok I have written it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really about the proper way to handle exceptions - the screenshot aspect is a just a detail.

This is a broad topic, but a starting point would be to say that you should treat all `WebDriverException` (parent of `NoSuchElementException`) as fatal errors as far as your test case / suite is concerned. If have more advanced needs and feel more confident then feel free to be more sophisticated, but this is the simplest and safest approach.

In that case you should **not** try to catch any of these exceptions in methods at the level of `get_element`, you should simply let them propagate / bubble-up to a single catch / finally block at the top level of your code (NB. this should **not** be in your tear-down code, this should be a wrapper around all test/application methods you run).

Once you have that catch-all handler, you can add your screenshot-saving code there, and you can be confident it will always be called, only for WebDriver errors (of any kind), and then only once.

It's up to you, but you needn't try to record screenshots in tear-down. By its nature that's not 'real' code, just scaffolding, so honest stacktraces should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your tip.  If i put the screenshot in a wrapper then any test method that fails the screenshot will be called.  I have never written a wrapper.  I will have to look this one up.

Comment: I showed my colleague what you said about the wrapper and he suggested i put the try/catch block around all my test methods.  I have pasted a test method below my question above.  Is it ok this way?

Comment: That’s largely what I meant by wrapper, yes. I’d prefer a function that executes a test handler (containing your code) within a try/catch-all-WebExceptions block, as it’s a bit cleaner. But there’s not much difference between the two things. You can see the basic approach.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much for your help.